# onAuthStateChanged return undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

i can log value of onAuthStateChanged but when i return it, extraReducers seem did not get it.
function check state of auth

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signOut
} from "firebase/auth";
```

```
export const checkUserSignIn = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/checkUSerSignIn",
  async () => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user)
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    });
  }
);
```

where i get return value

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {
    auth: {
      isLoading: false,
      isAuthenticate: false,
      user: null,
    },
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    //Check User SignIn
    builder
      .addCase(checkUserSignIn.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.auth.isLoading = true;
        console.log(`CheckUserSignIn Pending: ${action.payload}`);
      })
      .addCase(checkUserSignIn.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.auth.isLoading = false;
        action.payload
          ? (state.auth.isAuthenticate = true)
          : (state.auth.isAuthenticate = false);

        console.log(`CheckUserSignIn Fulfilled: ${action.payload}`);
      })
      .addCase(checkUserSignIn.rejected, (state, action) => {
        console.log(`CheckUserSignIn Rejected: ${action.error.message}`);
      });
    
    
  },
});
```

action.payload of fulfilled case always return undefined. how can i fix it?

have a nice day, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onAuthStateChanged` is an asynchronous call, but it doesn't return a promise itself. Even if it did, you're not returning anything from the top-level code in the `checkUserSignIn` function.

This is probably closer to what you need/want:

```
export const checkUserSignIn = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/checkUSerSignIn",
  async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) {
      const auth = getAuth();
      const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        unsubscribe();
        if (user) {
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }
      });
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: @Downvoter: please explain what is not useful about my answer, so I can improve it.