# Using async await to retrieve images from firebase storage in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, firebase-storage, use-effect

I have a useEffect hook with two functions inside of it, the first (fetchImages) gets all of the user images stored in firebase storage.
The second (loadImages) awaits for the fetchImages and sets the image into a state array. The problem is that the images array is returning empty unless you go to a different page and come back...then the array is filled with image urls. 
Im not sure if something is wrong with my useEffect hook or my placement of async await, or something else. The if check for currentUser is because currentUser returns as null on first load.

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]); // All user images from storage
useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser) {
        const fetchImages = async () => {
            setLoading(true)
            const result = await storage.ref(`images/${currentUser.id}`).listAll();
            console.log(result)
            const urlPromises = result.items.map((imageRef) =>
                imageRef.getDownloadURL()
            );
            console.log(urlPromises)
            return Promise.all(urlPromises);
        };

        const loadImages = async () => {
            const images = await fetchImages();
            setImages(images);
            setLoading(false);
        };
        loadImages();
    }
    console.log(loading)
}, []);
console.log(images, image)
```

The currentUser userContext file

```
export const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [currentUser, setUser] = useState(null);
    // const [currentUser, setUser] = useState('');
    
    useEffect(() => {
        let unsubscribeFromAuth = null;
        unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async userAuth => {
            if (userAuth) {
                const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);

                userRef.onSnapshot(snapShot => {
                    setUser({
                        id: snapShot.id,
                        ...snapShot.data()
                    });
                });
            } else {
                setUser(null)
            }
        });

        return () => {
            unsubscribeFromAuth();
        };
    }, [])
    // console.log(unsubscribeFromAuth)

    const toggleUser = () => {
        auth.signOut()
            .then(() => {
                window.localStorage.clear();
            })
            .then(() => {
                setUser(null)
            })
            .catch(e => console.log('There was a error:'(e)))
    }
```

Comment: "currentUser is because currentUser returns as null on first load", that is the issue. You could make a promise returning function that works with `onAuthStateChanged` and only execute this function once that resolves with a valid user.

Comment: Probably you should fix `currentUser` first by making sure that the page can load if and only if `currentUser` is set

Comment: Thank you for commenting @Alexander Staroselsky, ive been banging my head on a wall with this. Ill try to implement that now

Comment: For a promise-based approach, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70075205/onauthstatechanged-return-undefined/70075492#70075492

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `currentUser` to the `useEffect` hook's dependency array. When the `currentUser` state updates you want the side-effect to be fetching the related images, or clearing them out.

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]); // All user images from storage

useEffect(() => {
  if (currentUser) {
    const fetchImages = async () => {
      const result = await storage.ref(`images/${currentUser.id}`).listAll();
      const urlPromises = result.items.map((imageRef) =>
        imageRef.getDownloadURL()
      );
      return Promise.all(urlPromises);
    };

    const loadImages = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const images = await fetchImages();
        setImages(images);
      } catch(error) {
        // handle error, log it, show message, etc...
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
    loadImages();
  } else {
    setImages([]);
  }
}, [currentUser]);
```